# Poisson GLM Model with no linear predictor

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am trying to run code in R (I am very new at this), and I was given a very large dataset that I need to use to fit a poisson glm such as log(mu) = B0 +B1x1. Let Yi be the response count for subject i, and xi = 1(black) and xi = 0 (white).

The dataset can be found at www.stat.ufl.edu/~aa/glm/data.

I loaded the data, and I am having difficulty understanding a model for this.
Here is the code I have so far, but clearly I am missing something.

```
str(hdata)
head(hdata)
attach(hdata)
hfit = glm(count ~ factor(race), family = poisson(link = log))
summary(hfit)

#plot the model
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
plot(hfit)

#overdispersion test
library(AER)
dispersiontest(hfit, trafo =1)

#goodness of fit test
sum(resid(hfit, type="pearson")^2)
#pvalue
1 - pchisq(2279.873, 1306)
```

I need help with this model because I can't seem to separate each race, and I think that is what I need to do. When I ran the summary of hfit, I ended up with -2.38 as the intercept and 1.73 for factor(race)1. The AIC was 1122. Also, when I ran the overdispersion test I got c = 0.743, and if the model had equidispersion the c = 0. Am I right? Thank you